# Бесконечный переход при редирект

Tags: php

У меня есть файл **index.php** через который запускается весь сайт, я хочу сделать проверку в index на наличие **контролера install** и если он есть то перейти сразу на страницу /install, но у меня запускается бесконечный цикл переходов

```php
use application\core\Router;

if (file_exists('application/controllers/InstallController.php')) {
  header('Location: /install');
  exit;
}

spl_autoload_register(function ($class){
  $path = str_replace('\\', '/', $class.'.php');
  if (file_exists($path)) {
    require $path;
  }
});

session_start();


$router = new Router;
$router->run();
```

Comment: Так проверяйте url, что Вы сейчас не на `/install` уже, кроме проверки самого контроллера. Понятное дело, что если у Вас есть контроллер, на этом месте всегда будет отрабатывать условие и редиректить

Comment: Благодарю за помощь